# Eclipse looking for adb in wrong directory in Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I have Eclipse Juno installed, as well as adb 1.0.31 installed. Eclipse however is looking for adb in the wrong directory, so I get the following error when I try to run any code.

```
The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
You must restart adb and Eclipse.
Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/home/goister/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed.
```

How do I make Eclipse point to the right adb directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the directory to the ADT in the eclipse preferences, adb is included in that directory only!

Answer (score 0):

Window->Preferences->Android. Then change the SDK location

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse click windows->preference->

click 'android' on left side and specify the "sdk location:"

/home/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130219/sdk

Hope this helps